# What can I use instead of gnome-open?

Tags: gnome, command-line, xdg

What is a current replacement of `gnome-open` command (generic open of files based on the type)?

Before:

```
gnome-open mydoc.pdf  # opened PDF in default application
```

Now:

```
gnome-open
The program 'gnome-open' is currently not installed.  You can install
it by typing: sudo apt-get install libgnome2-0
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use `xdg-open` to open documents, like so:

```
xdg-open mydoc.pdf
```

This has a bonus of being desktop agnostic so it should work regardless of what desktop the user has installed. In GNOME itself `gnome-open` [has been replaced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101965/what-is-the-replacement-for-gnome-open-in-gnome) by `gvfs-open`.

References:

- [xdg-open info page on portland.freedesktop.org](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-open.html)
- [What is the replacement for gnome-open in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101965/what-is-the-replacement-for-gnome-open-in-gnome)
- [xdf-open vs. exo-open](http://budts.be/weblog/2011/07/xdf-open-vs-exo-open)

Comment: As of Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark, `gvfs-open` prints a deprecation warning to use `gio open` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `gio` too. For example `gio open notes.doc`.

Comment: Interesting, GIO seems to be a very strange thing. I wonder what can be useful for, other than "open".