# What is the replacement for gnome-open in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, xdg

`gnome-open` is typically used to open files from the CLI using their associated mime-type handler.

It doesn't appear to be installed by default anymore in 12.04. The errata has not been well documented or at least I have yet to find it.

Answer (score 15):

It appears that `gvfs-open` is taking over for the role of `gnome-open` in Precise and is installed by default.

`xdg-open` is also an option:

- [What can I use instead of gnome-open?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68961/what-can-i-use-instead-of-gnome-open)

Comment: as of Ubuntu 17.10 it looks like `gvfs-open` is also being deprecated in favor of `gio`.  At least that's according to the `gvfs-open` man page.