# What should be used instead of the deprecated gnome-open in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-open

I used to open images with `gnome-open` from a terminal, but after installing Ubuntu 18.04, the library is missing and if I search from `apt`, it shows:

```
➜  data git:(master) ✗ apt search gnome-open                    [18/06/14|11:35AM]
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libgnome2-bin/bionic 2.32.1-6 amd64
Deprecated GNOME 2 library - binary files
```

Are there any substitution for this command?

Thank you!

Comment: according to this question `gnome-open` was deprecated at least 6 years ago [Linux equivalent of the Mac OS X “open” command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/264395/995714), [Linux equivalent command for “open” command on Mac/Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/38984/241386)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I use instead of gnome-open?](https://askubuntu.com/q/68961/253474) and [What is the replacement for gnome-open in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/q/101965/253474)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`xdg-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xdg-open.1.html) wrapper instead, or [`gio`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gio.1.html) from [`libglib2.0-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libglib2.0-bin).  Both are installed by default in Ubuntu 18.04.

I'd prefer `xdg-open`, which wraps around several DE-specific openers (and will likely be kept updated to use whichever tools are currently supported). For example, the old GNOME3 tool used to be `gvfs-open`. `xdg-open` used to use `gvfs-open`, and after it was deprecated, `xdg-open` has been updated to use `gio open`.

In 18.04:

```
$ grep -e gio -e gvfs "$(command -v xdg-open)"
    if gio help open 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
        gio open "$1"
    elif gvfs-open --help 2>/dev/null 1>&2; then
        gvfs-open "$1"
...
```

In 16.04:

```
$ grep -e gio -e gvfs $(command -v xdg-open)
    if gvfs-open --help >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        gvfs-open "$1"
...
```

Comment: You could also define an alias from `gnome-open` to `xdg-open`. Old habits die hard!

Comment: I use xdg-open . & 
The & frees the terminal so it can be used for further commands without needint to close the GUI application spawned